# AffterInsert PROBLEM

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

I am attempting to update a field on the Opportunity object with the project that gets created (that is associated to the opportunity)

So basically the way things work is that when an opportunity is set to closed won a project gets created with a lookup relationship back to the opportunity. There is a field on the Project that automatically gets filled with the opportunity name, however the field on the Opportunity that is supposed to get filled with the project name is not being filled when the project is created.

I have attempted to write some code to update that field after the project is inserted. My logic seems correct however the field (`pse__Primary__Project__C`) is not being updated with the project name.

Here is the code..

```
public override void afterInsert(SObject so)
{
    pse__proj__c newProj = (pse__proj__c)so;

    list <pse__proj__c> projects = [SELECT ID, Name, pse__Opportunity__c FROM pse__proj__c];
    list <opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT ID, Name, pse__Primary_Project__c FROM Opportunity];

    for (Opportunity opps : opportunities){

    if (newProj.Created_by_Opp__c == true)
    {
        opps.pse__Primary_Project__c = newProj.id;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question as asked is that you do not perform `update` DML on the Opportunities you are changing to persist your changes back to the database.

However, before you move forward, you need to make some significant changes to your logic. Right now, you are querying every Opportunity and every Project in your database:

```
list <pse__proj__c> projects = [SELECT ID, Name, pse__Opportunity__c FROM pse__proj__c];
list <opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT ID, Name, pse__Primary_Project__c FROM Opportunity];
```

You're then not using `projects` at all, but you're setting the `pse__Primary_Project__c` field on every single Opportunity to the Id of the new record your method was passed.

You clearly need some kind of conditional logic here, as well as query filters, but we don't have enough information to say what that might be. I would strongly recommend completing the core Apex trigger and bulkification modules on Trailhead to learn more about how to write this type of functionality.

Additionally, I will note that it is very unusual to see a trigger handler framework that passes a single sObject to a handler method

```
public override void afterInsert(SObject so)
```

This isn't a good idea and will get you into bulkification trouble quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I have some concerns with your code (unfiltered queries on both `pse__proj__c` and `Opportunity` are red flags), but the issue at hand is probably that you're not performing an explicit DML update for your `Opportunity`.

"After" triggers do not automatically update records in `Trigger.new`. Since this appears to be an after trigger, you'll need to gather the Opportunities that you want to update into a list, and then explicitly `update <your list of opps>;` (because DML inside of a loop is just as bad as queries inside of a loop, maybe even worse)